# Validating a date range client side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have 2 TextBoxes that expect a date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`
Ex:

```
03/20/2013
```

Before I even bother to make the ajax call, I want to try and turn these into JS Dates. How could I check if:

```
Both Dates are in the mm/dd/yyyy format and if they are, then From must be less than to.
```

Thanks

Comment: Normally, I'd respond with the usual "What have you tried" but since I expect many people are going to attempt this, I'll post an answer anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using moment for this one.  Moment is a js library especially for dates, and evaluating dates.  Your two text boxes start off as strings, so you need to init 2 `moment()`'s with each.  Then verify they're both moment objects.  If so, it's then a simple matter to make sure the one is after the other.

Here's the link to moment: http://momentjs.com/

Here's code I may use:

```
var tb1 = $("#tb1").text(); // get string from "date box 1"
var tb2 = $("#tb2").text(); // get string from "date box 2"

//get timestamp val's so they can be used in moment initialization
var date1 = tb1.split("/"); 
var date2 = tb2.split("/");

    //create moments    
var mom1 = moment([date1[2], date1[1], date1[0]);
var mom2 = moment([date2[2], date2[1], date2[0]);

function validate(mom1, mom2){
    //validate both dates are actual dates
if (mom1.isValid() && mom2.isValid()){
            //compare timestamps to ensure 2nd timestamp is larger 
    if(mom1.unix() < mom2.unix()){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
            //strings aren't dates, return error
    $.error("not valid dates");
}
}
```

Comment: There's an even easier way of initing moment, but for the sake of users, i used the way that better shows what's happening.  You can also init like: `var mom1 = moment($("#tb1"),"MM/DD/YYYY");`